# Interpret knn.cv (R) results after applying on data set

Tags: r, dataset, knn

I have encountered a problem while using the k-nearest neighbors algorithm (with cross validation) on a data set in R, the `knn.cv` from the FNN package.
The data set consists of 4601 email cases with 58 attributes, with the 57 depending on character or word frequencies in the `emails(numerical, range [0,100])` , and the last one indicating if it is spam (value 1) or ham (value 0).

After indicating train and cl variables and using 10 neighbors, running the package presents a list of all the emails with values like `7.4032` at each column, which I don't know how to use. I need to find the percentage of spam and ham the package classifies and compare it with the correct percentage. How should I interpret these results?

Answer (score 4):

Given that the data set you describe matches (exactly) the spam data set in the **ElemStatLearn** package accompanying the well-known book by the same title, I'm wondering if this is in fact a homework assignment. If that's the case, it's ok, but you should add the homework tag to your question.

Here are some pointers.

The documentation for the function `knn.cv` says that it returns a vector of classifications, along with the distances and indices of the k nearest neighbors as "attributes". So when I run this:

```
out <- knn.cv(spam[,-58],spam[,58],k = 10)
```

The object `out` looks sort of like this:

```
> head(out)
[1] spam  spam  spam  spam  spam  email
Levels: email spam
```

The other values you refer to are sort of "hidden" as attributes, but you can see that they are there using `str`:

```
> str(out)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "email","spam": 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 - attr(*, "nn.index")= int [1:4601, 1:10] 446 1449 500 5 4 4338 2550 4383 1470 53 ...
 - attr(*, "nn.dist")= num [1:4601, 1:10] 8.10e-01 2.89 1.50e+02 2.83e-03 2.83e-03 ...
```

You can access those additional attributes via something like this:

```
nn.index <- attr(out,'nn.index')
nn.dist <- attr(out,'nn.dist')
```

Note that both of these objects end up being matrices of dimension 4601 x 10, which makes sense, since the documentation said that they recorded the index (i.e. row number) of the `k = 10` nearest neighbors as well as the distances to each.

For the last bit, you will probably find the `table()` function useful, as well as `prop.table()`.

Comment: Great, thanks. I 'll try that. And also, this is a part of my thesis, and i didn't know about the homework tag. I corrected it now.

Comment: Yeayyyy thanks a lot mate. Worked like a charm, with table() i got the results i needed.